# How to run a negative test in RACKET

Tags: testing, scheme, racket

I need to run all the end cases on my function , and they all must return true (meaning the test was passed). Now in boolean I know I can use `not`, as a negative on a false result and it should return true.

I'm having some trouble, running the same way (using `not`) on a wrong result, in functions that return an integer, and while writing the test I provide the wrong answer that the list should return and it's not working, can someone please help me, thanks!

Here's an example:

```
(test(not((sums '(1 2 3 5 3 3) '3 0)=> 2)))
```

While the test that will give me a passed test will be:

```
(test(sums '(1 2 3 5 3 3) '3 0)=> 3))
```

In this example the answer is the number of 3s in the list.

Comment: What testing module are you using? the syntax in the sample code doesn't look right, and why is the "positive" test also using `not`? Please post the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `sums` function returns `3` for the given parameters, a "normal" (positive) test would look like this:

```
(test (sums '(1 2 3 5 3 3) 3 0) ; actual value
      3)                        ; expected result
```

Now for the "negative" test you can use `(not (= ... ...))` to check that the result is *not* a certain value, for example (added indentation for clarity):

```
(test (not (= (sums '(1 2 3 5 3 3) 3 0) ; actual value
              2))                       ; the "wrong" answer
      #t)                               ; expected result
```